# InitialSessionState.CreateDefault () returns null

Tags: f#

I want to run XUnit tests in a PowerShell session with F# and want to create an InitialSessionState.

```
open System.Management.Automation.Runspaces

let initialSessionState = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault()
```

The above line returns `null` when I run the test.

Do I need to add something else when running it in F#?

Answer (score 0):

I think XUnit skips F#'s initialization code in this case. These two GitHub issues describe the issue in more detail:

- [Initialization of modules in F# is hit and miss](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/1221)
- [dotnet test fails at runtime when module values are used in tests (xunit/mstest)](https://github.com/dotnet/netcorecli-fsc/issues/79)

As a workaround, it looks like a dummy Program.fs will move the initialization to a static constructor:

```
module Program
let main _ = 0
```